# How do I Join different lines of text in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like below:

```
Date 1-Jan 2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
Duty
1    Bob   NaN   Bob   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
3    NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
```

What I want to achieve is adding a last line that with each date, if there are `Bob` in any `Duty`,the value will be "Bob", like below:

```
Date 1-Jan 2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
Duty
1    Bob   NaN   Bob   NaN
2    NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
3    NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
sum  Bob   NaN   Bob   Bob
```

What I tried is to use `pd.apply` like below:

`df.loc['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.sum())`

But what I get turns out:

```
Date 1-Jan 2-Jan 3-Jan     4-Jan
Duty
1    Bob   NaN   Bob       NaN
2    NaN   NaN   Bob       Bob
3    NaN   NaN   Bob       Bob
sum  NaN   NaN   BobBobBob NaN
```

I also tried seperate each line into several small Dataframe and try to `pd.merge()` them which is not work either.

Answer (score 3):

First we check if `any` of the values in each column are equal (`eq`) to `Bob`. Then we `append` those values at the bottom of our dataframe, while mapping `True > Bob` and `False > NaN`:

```
m = df.eq('Bob').any(axis=0).map({True: 'Bob', False: np.NaN})
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(m, columns=['sum']).T)
```

**Output**

```
    1-Jan 2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
0     Bob   NaN   Bob   NaN
1     NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
2     NaN   NaN   Bob   Bob
sum   Bob   NaN   Bob   Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

If need first non missing value per columns use [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) with `next` and `iter` for possible set default value if not exist first value:

```
df.loc['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x.dropna()),np.nan))
print (df)
     1-Jan  2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
Date                         
1      Bob    NaN   Bob   NaN
2      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
3      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
sum    Bob    NaN   Bob   Bob
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.loc['sum'] = df.stack().groupby(level=1).first()
print (df)
     1-Jan  2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
Date                         
1      Bob    NaN   Bob   NaN
2      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
3      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
sum    Bob    NaN   Bob   Bob
```

If need test value `Bob`:

```
df.loc['sum'] =  df.eq('Bob').any().map({True: 'Bob', False: np.nan})
print (df)
     1-Jan  2-Jan 3-Jan 4-Jan
Date                         
1      Bob    NaN   Bob   NaN
2      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
3      NaN    NaN   Bob   Bob
sum    Bob    NaN   Bob   Bob
```